# aliases on two outer joins

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, alias

i'm trying to run a query resulting in 2 outer joins on the same table profile_data. So eventually i want a table resulting user | friend | degree | user_value | friend_value, where friend_value is dependent on the relation_degree. the first outer join works, but when i add the second one it gives me an error. I think it has to do with the aliases. Can somebody push me in the right direction? many thanks!

```
         SELECT degrees.User, 
                degrees.friend, 
                degrees.relation_degree, 
                a.wp_bp_xprofile_data.value as user_value, 
                b.wp_bp_xprofile_data.value as user_value
           FROM degrees
LEFT OUTER JOIN a.wp_bp_xprofile_data
             ON degrees.User=wp_bp_xprofile_data.user_id
          WHERE wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id =  CASE
                                                  WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 1 Then  2
                                                  WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 2 Then  6
                                                  WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 3 Then  7
                                                END
LEFT OUTER JOIN b.wp_bp_xprofile_data
            ON degrees.friend=wp_bp_xprofile_data.user_id
         WHERE wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id =  CASE
                                                 WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 1 Then  2
                                                 WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 2 Then  6
                                                 WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 3 Then  7
                                               END
```

Comment: You have 2 WHERE clauses.

Comment: yes for 2 outer joins, one for each join/columns to create...

Comment: You do not use a WHERE clause per join. You have a single WHERE clause for a query (or sub query). If you want to specify it on the join then you just put it in the ON clause.

Comment: allright cool! i didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have 2 table joins to the same table without aliasing the table name, and also 2 WHERE clauses.

Try something like this:-

```
SELECT degrees.User, 
        degrees.friend, 
        degrees.relation_degree, 
        wp_bp_xprofile_data1.value as user_value_1, 
        wp_bp_xprofile_data2.value as user_value_2
FROM degrees
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data wp_bp_xprofile_data1
ON degrees.User=wp_bp_xprofile_data1.user_id
AND wp_bp_xprofile_data1.field_id =  CASE
                                        WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 1 Then  2
                                        WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 2 Then  6
                                        WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 3 Then  7
                                    END
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data wp_bp_xprofile_data2
ON degrees.friend=wp_bp_xprofile_data2.user_id
AND wp_bp_xprofile_data2.field_id = CASE
                                        WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 1 Then  2
                                        WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 2 Then  6
                                        WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 3 Then  7
                                    END
```

Comment: thanks kickstart for your answer. i get  the following error:#1142 - SELECT command denied to user '<Username>'@'s317.zeptor.local' for table 'wp_bp_xprofile_data' . pretty strange because i know i own these rights

Comment: That sounds like a permissions issue and I can't see anything in the SQL that would falsely trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

You have **where** in the middle.
You need to put **where** at the very end of query.
 If you want to filter joined data no at the end but during join you can filter  using
"on .... AND wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id =  CASE... "

but the biggest deal here is that you don't have aliases on tables.

you need to do

```
from ...
left outer join a.wp_bp_xprofile_data AS firstAlias
on firstAlias.someColumn = ...
...
left outer join a.wp_bp_xprofile_data AS secondAlias
on secondAlias.someColumn = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this......

```
SELECT degrees.User, degrees.friend, degrees.relation_degree, a.wp_bp_xprofile_data.value as user_value1, b.wp_bp_xprofile_data.value as user_value2
From degrees
left outer join a.wp_bp_xprofile_data
on degrees.User=a.wp_bp_xprofile_data.user_id
where a.wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id =  CASE

WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 1 Then  2
WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 2 Then  6
WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 3 Then  7

END

left outer join b.wp_bp_xprofile_data
on degrees.friend=b.wp_bp_xprofile_data.user_id
where b.wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id =  CASE

WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 1 Then  2
WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 2 Then  6
WHEN degrees.relation_degree = 3 Then  7

END
```